# Remove a property in an object immutably

Tags: javascript, immutability, redux

I am using Redux. In my reducer I'm trying to remove a property from an object like this:

```
const state = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: {
       x: '42',
       y: '43'
    },
}
```

And I want to have something like this without having to mutate the original state:

```
const newState = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: {
       x: '42',
    },
}
```

I tried:

```
let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
delete newState.c.y
```

but for some reasons, it deletes the property from both states.

Could help me to do that?

Comment: Note that `Object.assign` creates only a [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy) of `state` and therefore `state.c` and `newState.c` will point to the same shared object. You tried to delete property `y` from the shared object `c` and not from the new object `newState`.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

How about using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax?

```js
const original = {
  foo: 'bar',
  stack: 'overflow',
};

// If the name of the property to remove is constant
const { stack, ...withoutFirst } = original;
console.log(withoutFirst); // Will be { "foo": "bar" }

// If the name of the property to remove is from a variable
const key = 'stack'
const { [key]: value, ...withoutSecond } = original;
console.log(withoutSecond); // Will be { "foo": "bar" }

// To do a deep removal with property names from variables
const deep = {
  foo: 'bar',
  c: {
   x: 1,
   y: 2
  }
};

const parentKey = 'c';
const childKey = 'y';
// Remove the 'c' element from original
const { [parentKey]: parentValue, ...noChild } = deep;
// Remove the 'y' from the 'c' element
const { [childKey]: removedValue, ...childWithout } = parentValue;
// Merge back together
const withoutThird = { ...noChild, [parentKey]: childWithout };
console.log(withoutThird); // Will be { "foo": "bar", "c": { "x": 1 } }
```

Comment: wonderful,without extra library,make use of es6 and simple enough.

Comment: Nice!  Here's an es6 helper function to go along with it `const deleteProperty = ({[key]: _, ...newObj}, key) => newObj;`.  Usage: `deleteProperty({a:1, b:2}, "a");` gives `{b:2}`

Comment: Note that the deep removal example will crash if `deep['c']` is empty, so in a general case, you might want to add a check for the presence of the key.

Comment: In the first example you would be left over with an unused variable `stack`.

Comment: plugged this utility function right into my reducer 
function removeProperty(original, property) {
  let { [property]: _, ...newObj } = original;
  return newObj
}

Comment: i made an small function to remove a key from a no deep object on typescript

` function omitObjectKey<T>(key: keyof T, object: T): T {
 const { [key]: value, ...objectWithoutkey } = object;

 return objectWithoutkey as T
}`

hope it helps :3

Answer (score 50):

I find ES5 array methods like `filter`, `map` and `reduce` useful because they always return new arrays or objects. In this case I'd use `Object.keys` to iterate over the object, and `Array#reduce` to turn it back into an object.

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    c: Object.keys(state.c).reduce((result, key) => {
        if (key !== 'y') {
            result[key] = state.c[key];
        }
        return result;
    }, {})
});
```

Comment: chiming in with my slight change to make it clearer IMO... also lets you omit multiple properties.

const omit = ['prop1', 'prop2']
...
if (omit.indexOf(key) === -1) result[key] = state.c[key]
return result;
...

Comment: ES6 equivalent to get a copy of `myObject` with key `myKey` removed: `Object.keys(myObject).reduce((acc, cur) => cur === myKey ? acc : {...acc, [cur]: myObject[cur]}, {})`

Comment: This won't work if the object has inherited properties...

Comment: @JuanMendes React state should just be key-value pairs. Inherited properties are a red herring.

Comment: Sure, the question does mention redux... It's just that it's its title doesn't mention anything and it's the top result when looking for ways to remove from an object so it may as well have generic information that's useful to everyone

Answer (score 45):

You can use `_.omit(object, [paths])` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library

path can be nested for example: `_.omit(object, ['key1.key2.key3'])`

Comment: Unfortunately, `_.omit` cannot delete deep properties (what OP was asking). There's [`omit-deep-lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/omit-deep-lodash) module for this purpose.

Comment: Going off what @AlexM was saying. I found it useful, and it might be more appropriate, to us ```_.cloneDeep(obj)``` from lodash. That copies the object easily and then you can simply use js ```delete obj.[key]``` to remove the key.

Comment: Agree w/ @AlexJ, cloneDeep works perfectly and you can use the spread syntax with it as well:  ..._.cloneDeep(state) for Redux

Answer (score 36):

Just use ES6 object destructuring feature

```js
const state = {
    c: {
       x: '42',
       y: '43'
    },
}

const { c: { y, ...c } } = state // generates a new 'c' without 'y'

console.log({...state, c }) // put the new c on a new state
```

Comment: `const {y, ...c} = state.c` might be a little clearer than having two `c`'s on the left hand side.

Comment: beware: this doesn't work for an object keyed by integers

Comment: From the below answer, if you need to reference the variable name to be deleted:
`const name = 'c'` then you can do
`const {[name]:deletedValue, ...newState} = state` then return `newState` in your reducer. This is for a top level key deletion

Answer (score 24):

That's because you are copying the value of `state.c` to the other object. And that value is a pointer to another javascript object. So, both of those pointers are pointing to the same object.

Try this:

```
let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
console.log(newState == state); // false
console.log(newState.c == state.c); // true
newState.c = Object.assign({}, state.c);
console.log(newState.c == state.c); // now it is false
delete newState.c.y;
```

You can also do a deep-copy of the object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) and you'll find what's best for you.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! `state.c` is a reference, and the reference is being copied just fine. Redux wants a normalized state shape, which means using ids instead of references when nesting state. Check out the redux docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Answer (score 18):

How about this:

```
function removeByKey (myObj, deleteKey) {
  return Object.keys(myObj)
    .filter(key => key !== deleteKey)
    .reduce((result, current) => {
      result[current] = myObj[current];
      return result;
  }, {});
}
```

It filters the key that should be deleted then builds a new object from the remaining keys and the initial object. The idea is stolen from Tyler McGinnes awesome reactjs program.

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qenasa/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 14):

As of 2019, another option is to use the `Object.fromEntries` method. It has reached stage 4.

```
const newC = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(state.c).filter(([key]) => key != 'y')
)
const newState = {...state, c: newC}
```

The nice thing about it is that it handles integer keys nicely.

Answer (score 13):

```
function dissoc(key, obj) {
  let copy = Object.assign({}, obj)
  delete copy[key]
  return copy
}
```

Also, if looking for a functional programming toolkit, look at [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com).

Answer (score 10):

You may use [Immutability helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) in order to unset an attribute, in your case:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const updatedState = update(state, {
  c: {
    $unset: ['y']
  }
});
```

Comment: Then how to delete all the property "y" of every array object item?

Comment: @5ervant I think that's another question, but I'd suggest you to map the array and apply any of the given solutions here

Answer (score 6):

It's easy with [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/):

```
const newState = state.deleteIn(['c', 'y']);
```

[description of deleteIn()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/deleteIn)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an easy 1-liner you can use that allows you to partially apply the prop you want to remove.  This makes it easy to pass to `Array.map`.

```
const removeProp = prop => ({ [prop]: _, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest })
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
const newArr = oldArr.map(removeProp('deleteMe'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is that you are not deep cloning your initial state. So you have a shallow copy.

You could use spread operator

```
  const newState = { ...state, c: { ...state.c } };
  delete newState.c.y
```

Or following your same code

```
let newState = Object.assign({}, state, { c: Object.assign({}, state.c) });
delete newState.c.y
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use

```
Object.assign({}, existingState, {propToRemove: undefined})
```

I realise this isn't actually removing the property but for almost all purposes <sup>1</sup> its functionally equivalent. The syntax for this is much simpler than the alternatives which I feel is a pretty good tradeoff.

<sup>1</sup> If you are using `hasOwnProperty()`, you will need to use the more complicated solution.

Answer (score 1):

I use this pattern

```
const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      delete newState.show;
      return newState;
```

but in book i saw another pattern

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { name: undefined } )
```

Comment: The second one, does not remove the key. It just sets it to undefined.

Answer (score 1):

**utility ;))**

```
const removeObjectField = (obj, field) => {

    // delete filter[selectName]; -> this mutates.
    const { [field]: remove, ...rest } = obj;

    return rest;
}
```

**action type**

```
const MY_Y_REMOVE = 'MY_Y_REMOVE';
```

**action creator**

```
const myYRemoveAction = (c, y) => {

    const result = removeObjectField(c, y);

        return dispatch =>
            dispatch({
                type: MY_Y_REMOVE,
                payload: result
            })
    }
```

**reducer**

```
export default (state ={}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case myActions.MY_Y_REMOVE || :
      return { ...state, c: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in some of the answers already, it's because you are trying to modify a nested state ie. one level deeper. A canonical solution would be to add a reducer on the `x` state level:

```
const state = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: {
       x: '42',
       y: '43'
    },
}
```

Deeper level reducer

```
let newDeepState = Object.assign({}, state.c);
delete newDeepState.y;
```

Original level reducer

```
let newState = Object.assign({}, state, {c: newDeepState});
```

Answer (score -2):

**Use a combination of Object.assign, JSON.parse and JSON.stringify**

```js
const obj1 = { a: "a", b: "b" };
const obj2 = { c: "c", a: undefined };

const merged = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

const sanitized = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(merged));

console.log(sanitized); // -> { b: "b", c: "c" }
```