# ng-model bind only $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that returns dict. In my controller i set it to $scope variable:

```
.controller('viewCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.mydict = myService.mydict;
}
```

But then when i change value in input:

```
<input ng-model="mydict.mykey">
```

`mykey` value changed in service `myService.mydict` too. But i want only change it in `$scope.mydict` variable.

I tried do this:

```
var localDict = myService.mydict;
$scope.mydict = localDict;
```

This didn't work. When use ng-value - then it doesn't track it after change.

Comment: Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401098/remove-a-property-in-an-object-immutably/34401158)

Comment: Dictionary will return more than one value. So use it as mydict[0].mykey