# Trying to do a filter method on an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a delete todo and I want to remove the item from the object "byIds" with the specific id.
It will be like a filter for arrays but for the object.
I don't know what's so complicated hope for help I believe its stupid

```js
import { ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, DELETE_TODO } from "../actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  allIds: [],
  byIds: {},
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO: {
      const { id, content } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: [...state.allIds, id],
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            content,
            completed: false,
          },
        },
      };
    }
    case TOGGLE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            ...state.byIds[id],
            completed: !state.byIds[id].completed,
          },
        },
      };
    }
    // of course its toggling but it doesn't even get there
    case DELETE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: state.allIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
        byIds: state.byIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```js
{
  todos: {
    allIds: [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ],
    byIds: {
      '1': {
        content: 'Test1',
        completed: false
      },
      '2': {
        content: 'Test2',
        completed: false
      },
      '3': {
        content: 'test3',
        completed: false
      },
      '4': {
        content: 'test4',
        completed: false
      }
    }
  },
  visibilityFilter: 'all'
}
```

That for the one who asked me to console log the byIds hope that will help me

Comment: can you share the data shape for `console.log(byIds)` add it to the post.

Comment: Redux is unnecesary for this question, would be easier if you abstracted this to react, or even better simply JS.

Comment: @NicolasHevia cleared the tag

Comment: @BARNOWL I did it hope for help, I only want to delete a todo

Comment: does any of the answers below help ?

Comment: @Ethanolle check our answers.

Comment: Not yet I tried and answered to every one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to iterate through the `keys` of `byids` object and take only the ones you need.

```
case DELETE_TODO: {
  const { id } = action.payload;
  let newObj = {}

  Object.keys(state.byIds).forEach(function(key) {
    if (key !== id) {
      newObj[key] = state.byIds[key]
   }
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    allIds: state.allIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
    byIds: newObj 
  };
}
```

In case your id is not a string but a number, you need to check with `key != id` and not `key !== id`

Comment: @Ethanolle does this help ?

Comment: Line 42:  'byids' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 44:  'byids' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @BARNOWL i like the other answer with destructuring to be honest. my solution is classic js, the others are ES6 style :)

Comment: Line 42:  'byIds' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 44:  'byIds' is not defined  no-undef Sanme Probleme

Comment: yes of course... it is `state.byIds` not just `byIds`. my mistake

Comment: Nop that just deleting my allIds state but not the byIds. Something that looks so simple that's killing me.

Comment: ok so final solution is this. i don;t how what type is your id, but try `key != id` instead of `key !== id`

Comment: Bingo, can you explain to me? because even my vsCode is expecting something else.

Comment: `==` will check the value but `===` will check the type too. so if you are trying to compare 1 with "1" and the first will result to true because values are the same and second to false because first is number and second string. same is for `!=`

Comment: If I see you in the street ill give you a kiss, Thanks sory for being such a young noobie

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the id out like this:

```
case DELETE_TODO: {
  const id = action.payload.id;
  const { [id]: _, ...filteredState } = state.byIds; 
  // ^ this takes id from state and puts it in variable _,
  // everything else is packed into filteredState

  return {
    ...state,
    allIds: state.allIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
    byIds: filteredState,
  };
}
```

---

Edit:
Extra notes for anyone wondering about the syntax above, see these links:

[Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), how we are grabbing `[id]`

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), how we are packing back into `...filteredState`

[Awesome comment explaining destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227198/6162550)

Comment: Nop that just deleting my allIds state but not the byIds

Comment: Ah from reading the other comments it looks like the reason it does not work is because you are passing in a number as `action.payload.id`, but the keys in `byIds` are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rest syntax to exclude the id when creating the new object.

```
case DELETE_TODO: {
  const { id } = action.payload;
  const { [id]: _, ...restByIds } = state.byIds;
  return {
    ...state,
    allIds: state.allIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
    byIds: restByIds,
  };
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that was called rest syntax.

Comment: Nop that just deleting my allIds state but not the byIds

Comment: @Ethanolle, Did you actually try it though? `restByIds` will contain the filtered byIds object...